# Azure from Powershell, deploying to the wrong subscription

Tags: powershell, script, azure, subscription, azure-cli

I'm trying to figure out if i deploy something from my powershell, that it is deploying to the wrong subscription which is in no way connected to eachother, except for that i have previously been logged in with it in powershell.

I have used `az logout` and `az account clear` to make sure it doesn't have any knowledge of the other account.

If i list any resources it would do it on the correct account, but creating would be on the second account.

If i do a `az account list` it only shows the correct account.

Any ideas of how to fix this ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else needing the answer, the AZ module the other modules are not working correctly together, as my context was set differently in AzureRM than in Az.

When i attempted to do the deployments through for an example `az group create` instead of `new-azresourcegroup` it deployed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try using the select command first, to select which tenant you are deploying to:

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscripitionID <ID of sub> -TenantId <ID of Azure Tenant>
```